# How the user of my Django app can create "customized" tasks?

Tags: python, django, task, customization, celery

I am new to Celery and I can't figure out at all how I can do what I need. I have seen how to create tasks by myself and change Django's file settings.py in order schedule it. But I want to allow users to create "customized" tasks.

I have a Django application that is supposed to give the user the opportunity to create the products they need (files that gather weather information) and to send them emails at a frequency they choose.

I have a database that contains the parameters of every product like geographical time, other parameters and frequency. I also have a script *sendproduct.py* that sends the product to the user.

Now, how can I simply create for each product, user created a task that execute my script with the given parameters and the given frequency?

Answer (score 0):

As you know how to create & execute tasks, it's very easy to allow customers to create tasks.

You can create a simple form to get required information from the user. You can also have a profile page or some page where you can show user preferences.

The above form helps to get data(like how frequently he needs to receive eamils) from user. Once the form is submitted, you can trigger a task asynchronously which will does processing & send emails to customer.

Comment: I have already made such a form and I store the user's information in my database. My question is (I know I sound a little bit confused) : should I create only one task that browse my database and that send emails for each product of my user at the right time, or is it possible to write a script that create automatically a task for each product when it is created ? 
In practice, should I make one Celery task or as many Celery tasks as there are products ?

Comment: There is no need to create as many celery tasks as products. Only one celery task will do the job.